# Why modified reference does not change out of thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

I am currently practising multi threading and memory management, and I am trying to implement the following: Multiple threads will push requests into a deque, and another thread will pop them and print them.

The function `pusher` gets references to : a mutex, a condition variable, a message deque, a flag indicating whether deque is written to by another thread, and a message to push repeatedly.

The function `popper` gets the same parameters except for the message.

My code is as following:

```
#include <thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<deque>
#include<iostream>

void pusher(std::deque<int>& dq, std::mutex& mu, std::condition_variable& cond, bool& flag, int value)//function to insert value into deque
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        cond.wait(locker, [dq, flag]() {return flag == false; });
        flag = true;
        dq.push_back(value);
        std::cout << "pushing: " << value << std::endl;
        flag = false;
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_all();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void popper(std::deque<int>& dq, std::mutex& mu, std::condition_variable& cond, bool& flag)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
        cond.wait(locker, [dq, flag]() {return (!dq.empty() && flag == false); });
        flag = true;
        std::cout << "popping: " << dq.front() << std::endl;
        dq.pop_front();
        flag = false;
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_all();
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::deque<int>dq;
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    bool flag = false;
    std::thread th1(pusher, std::ref(dq), std::ref(mu), std::ref(cond), std::ref(flag), 1);
    std::thread th2(popper, std::ref(dq), std::ref(mu), std::ref(cond), std::ref(flag));
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When running this code I run into a problem: the `popper` thread does not wake up, and the pusher thread continues indefinitely.
However, when attempting the same this time with pointers instead of threads, all works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include<deque>


void pusher(std::mutex* mu, std::condition_variable* cond, std::deque<int>* dq, int* flag, int value)//function to insert value into deque
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(*mu);
        cond->wait(locker, [dq, flag]() {return *flag == false; });
        *flag = true;
        dq->push_back(value);
        std::cout << "pushing: " << value << std::endl;
        *flag = false;
        locker.unlock();
        cond->notify_all();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void popper(std::mutex* mu, std::condition_variable* cond, std::deque<int>* dq, int* flag)//function to extract values from deque
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(*mu);
        cond->wait(locker, [dq, flag]() {return (!dq->empty() && *flag == false); });
        *flag = true;
        std::cout << "popping: " << dq->front() << std::endl;
        dq->pop_front();
        *flag = false;
        locker.unlock();
        cond->notify_all();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int flag = false;
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    std::deque<int> dq;
    std::thread th1(pusher, &mu, &cond, &dq, &flag, 1);

    std::thread th2(popper, &mu, &cond, &dq, &flag);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that somehow the deque is not being modified outside of pushing thread, and thus the condition of the condition variable is not fulfilled.
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
    cond->wait(locker, [dq, flag]() {return (!dq->empty() && *flag == false); });
```

Even though `dq, flag` are references, the above captures them by-value. It's is the same issue for which you used `std::ref()` when starting the threads.

Change it to `&dg, &flag` and the code should work.

**But** you don't need the `flag` here at all. `dq.empty()` is the only condition required to unblock the popper (and pusher doesn't need to wait at all).

Comment: The flag is required for the addition of other threads running the pusher function